# Postgres pg_hba.conf Configuration

Tags: python, postgresql, intellij

I'm trying to develop a python application using Postgres. Unfortunately everytime I do a

```
db.session.commit()
```

I get this as an error:

```
OperationalError: (OperationalError) fe_sendauth: no password supplied None None
```

After playing around with the pg_hba.config file I still get the same error. The respective file is currently as follows:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer
local   all             alex                                    trust

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

Would somebody be so kind as to help me with the right configuration for this file running on Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty nice walk-through.....
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL

First find the file **pg_hba.config**. Usually found here:

```
 /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf
```

OR

```
 /etc/postgresql/[VERSION]/main/pg_hba.conf
```

Find this commented-out line:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
```

And Underneath Change '???' to md5:

```
local   all             postgres               probably 'peer'
```

To:

```
local   all             postgres                                md5
```

This is because Ubuntu uses md5 with postgres instead of peer authentication

Then run this command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql reload
```